# Display what is selected in a dropdown : Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-4

I have the following HTML,

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
      Dropdown button
    </button>
    <div id="custom" class="dropdown-menu">
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Normal</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Active</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Disabled</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script>
document.getElementById('custom').addEventListener("click", myFunction);

function myFunction() {
  alert(this.textContent);
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

i am trying to `alert` and set the `button` text to what is selected in `drop-down`.

I can able to get the value by setting an id to `dropdown-item` and read it in JS. However i have n-number of `dropdown-item` , so adding id is not feasible.

There are solutions available in `jQuery` but how can i do this without using `jQuery`. ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could access the `innerHTML` or `innerText` property of the target element:

```js
document.getElementById('custom').addEventListener("click", myFunction);

function myFunction(e) {
  alert(e.target.innerText);
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
      Dropdown button
    </button>
    <div id="custom" class="dropdown-menu">
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Normal</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Active</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Disabled</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

From your query, I suspect that you want to access the selected item of the dropdown in the dropdown click event.

You can get the selected element from the click event argument (i.e **e.target**). So, you can easily access the selected element text from that element (i.e **e.target.text**).

Answer (score 1):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button type="button" id="dropdown-button" class="btn btn-warning dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
      Dropdown button
    </button>
    <div id="custom" class="dropdown-menu">
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Normal</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Active</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Disabled</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script>
document.getElementById('custom').addEventListener("click", myFunction);

function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById('dropdown-button').innerText = event.target.innerText;
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the parent element of the  links.
I mean you can get "#custom" element by the javascript code.

var parElement = document.getElementByID("#custom"); // will return you the element.

And you can get the children of the custom element by calling

parElement.childNodes  //this will return the child nodes.

You can get the length of child nodes, so you can fully control the  links.